# Modifying a static member field inside a static asnyc method

Tags: c#

I have an async function called increaseInterest and it is defined in the scope of the class whose member I am trying to modify. But the thing is that whenever I try to go through the dictionary referencing each key I get an error that cannot reference something in an asnyc function

As mentioned earlier I tried going through it with a foreach and referncing each value in the dictionary but that didn't work. I also tried casting the e into the `Bank` class but that didn't end up working either

Here is the code

```cs
static class Bank
{

    static private System.Timers.Timer timer;

    static public ThreadLocal<ConcurrentDictionary<User, Int64>> debt;

    static public async void increaseInterest(object? e, ElapsedEventArgs args)
    {
        
    }
}
```

Edit:

Here is the line that causes the error:

```
 foreach(ref var key in debt.Value)
{

}
```

Comment: What exact error do you get, and which line causes it?

Comment: This isn't valid C#, you want to use `foreach` - `in`, not `:`. Also you may not be able to `ref` those as I think enumerators don't support that at the moment.

Comment: @Ray sorry for the syntax error I fixed it in my question. If references in enumerators are not supported, what other choice do I have(I do c++ most of the time so c# is quite alien to me)

Comment: Why have you shown the broken code only in the screenshot (which is harder to read) rather than in the plain-text, easy-to-read code? Please remove the screenshot, but make sure that the code actually contains the problem. (And ideally *only* the problem - very little of the code presented is relevant.)

Comment: I thought that the screen shot would be more helpful. I am changing that in a moment

Comment: Just remove `ref `. Why do you think you need it?

Comment: @Magnus I think that I need it to modify the dictionary's values

Comment: In a `ConcurrentDictionary` you will have to use `TryUpdate` anyway. You cannot `ref` into it as this would break the thread safety. If `Value` is a reference type (i.e., a class) you can change its properties or fields, as long as you don't change the key.

Comment: Using threadLocal in an async function is also highly suspect. There is an AsyncLocal for that specific purpose. You may also need to use `AddOrUpdate` or `TryUpdate` to update values safely. But writing thread safe code is difficult, and global variables will not certainly not help. Note for example that `Timer` is not thread safe. It might be useful to explain what you are actually trying to do. There might be much better ways to do it than your current attempt.

Comment: Additional concerns: when does this dictionary ever empty? what is `User`? is it appropriate to use as a key, and what object graph does it keep alive? would some unique key *of* the user (the id) be a better choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update the value this is how to do it:

```
static public async void increaseInterest(object? e, ElapsedEventArgs args)
{
    foreach (var item in debt.Value)
    {
        debt.Value.TryUpdate(item.Key, item.Value + 1);
    }
}
```